# How do I force solve_ivp to take a smaller time step from within the function it calls

Tags: python, scipy, runge-kutta, convergence, timestep

I have a function call of the form

```
ans = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(dfdz, zbounds, f0, method='RK45', args=argslist, t_eval = zspan, vectorized=True)
```

If the solver takes a timestep that's too big, `dfdz` will sometimes fail to converge. I want `dfdz` to be able to force the solver to take a smaller step. How do I do this?

I tried to have `dfdz` return -f (i.e. "in this time step, all values become zero") hoping that would lead to non-convergence, or at least make it obvious that it failed. Instead, I see cases where my output ans jumps down, but not all the way to zero, and then the solver keeps integrating as if nothing happened.

Comment: Do you need smaller timesteps because you have a stiff ODE? If that's the case, you should be using a method that's better suited for stiff ODEs, such as "LSODA", "Radau", or "BDF", as per the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html).

Comment: I can change the method, but that doesn't guarantee that it won't try to take a step that's too big, and when it does, I still need to have some way to force the solver to take a smaller step.

Comment: Stiff ODEs require smaller steps. So, if that is what is causing the RK4 solver to fail, then switching to a solver that can recognize that should fix the issue. Plus, "Rabau" and "BDF" are implicit methods, which (if I remember correctly) are unconditionally stable.

Comment: Organically you get smaller steps if you reduce the error tolerances. There is also a parameter for the maximal step size, if you want to force it. // Please describe what "converge" means here, and how you observe it for correct behavior. // To explore the actual steps, leave the default of `t_eval=None` so you get the actually computed steps as return.

Comment: dfdz is a somewhat complex function: It includes a shooting method which needs to find a zero (determine an initial condition from a known final state). Sometimes it cannot find this zero, and I found that if scipy.integrate.solve_ivp takes smaller steps, that can fix the numerical instability. I'm trying using max_step right now, but that's a very inefficient solution. If my function requires the first two steps to be O(10^(-17)) then future steps can be O(1) there's a lot lost by setting max_step = 10^(-17). Those numbers are what I saw when I made it create an output excel log file.

Comment: This chaining of solvers is usually sub-optimal. If the system is some kind of DAE, one should use a DAE solver or do manual index reduction until an ODE system remains. It is possible that you will need to implement your own solver to get some kind of simultaneous solution of of the two parts of the system. It is also possible that modern packages like differentialequations.jl already contain appropriate solver combinations.

Comment: Another example: I have a system where I know that a value (concentration) will decrease from 0 to L.  I know that if the concentration increases at a given step, that is a sign of numerical instability, and I want the solver to detect this and take a smaller step instead of proceeding to amplify the error...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Julia offers the capabilities I need https://www.youtube.com/live/KPEqYtEd-zY?si=zveHs2rYd518PBoD

I'm still working it out for my code, but this tutorial has been very helpful so I'm posting it here for anyone else who has the same question and finds this thread

EDIT: I was asked to clarify. As discussed here https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/basics/faq/ isoutofdomain does what I asked for in the opening question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).